# Is a way to control view of scrollable list to display component by 0.5 of other components in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to control scrollable list in a row, by display component/widget in a scrollable row  by half and full of other component in a scrollable list as shown below .

[image: see example below]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Could you specify?

Comment: @PascalGehring, in a scrollable row list, I want  user to be able to know this is scrollable view by display component in a list by half and full in a  scrollable list , check the image above

Comment: You want to show the first element full and the other half, so that the user gets that the widget is scrollable?

Comment: Exactly @PascalGehring

Comment: Could you provide the code you use for the boxes?

Comment: no that is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Give each box more than half of the screen width. In this way, the first list item will cover more than half of the screen, and the next item will be half visible. You can give the width like this

**MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6**